# Store filename in variable and create tables with the filename in SSIS

Tags: sql, ssis

I've few excel source files in one folder in SSIS. I want to pull data from these excel files and load in to SQL tables.
My problem is I want to save all the files names one by one and want to create SQL table with exactly same name as filename
and then want to load each excel file in corresponding table.
Please help me how to create a package for this.

Answer (score 3):

Jayvee has presented the high level view which is good enough! Let me add in bit detail.

I am assuming that you have dynamic Excel file connection.

1. Declare a variable and named it as **FileName**. And assign it the first file name which is available in the folder.
   [image: FileName]
2. Place **Foreach Loop Container** and double click on it. Specify the **Folder:** and **Files:** as shown in image below.
   [image]
3. In the same **Foreach Loop Editor**, go to **Variable Mappings**. Select **Variable** from drop down list. This is the same variable which we defined in first step. Set its **Index** to **0**. Click **OK**.
   [image]
4. Remaining task is same as Jayvee explained.

See [this](http://the-simple-programmer.blogspot.com/2010/02/use-variable-as-table-name-in-ssis.html) link for further help. And this for [Result Set Property Not Set Correctly](http://suneethasdiary.wordpress.com/tag/resultset-property-not-set-correctly/). I think setting **ResultSet** property to **SingleRow** will do the job.

Comment: Thanks.. I've done this but I am still getting error.. This is what I am doing in Execute Sql Task..
My Sql Statement is like this
Create Table ?
(Id Int,
Name varchar(20)
)
Is this fine or I am missing something?

Comment: And then I am mapping User::FileName variable in Parameter Mapping

Answer (score 0):

your control flow should look like this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this.. Please can you explain this in detail, and What are the properties I need to set in Execute SQL and Data flow tasks?

Comment: And How do I set table name dynamically in OLEDB destination?

Comment: for each container read the folder and update a variable with file name. Execute sql create the table based on the variable. Data flow loads the file. I'm assuming you know the structure of the file. There are other options using rename and/or script tasks, depends on your requirements.

Comment: Actually I am trying the same thing but I am getting error in Execute SQl task while creating tables. I am getting error like "Result set is not proper". Please can you let me know what are the properties we need to change in Execute SQL Task?

Comment: if you are just creating the table your result set property should be set to none

Comment: Yes, Resultset is set to None but even then I am getting same error.

Comment: please post your sql and a screenshot of the properties