# Batch File in SSIS

Tags: ssis

I am producing two files from an SSIS package.

One is the main content and the other is the header.

After I have output both files  - I am then merging them using an Execute Process Task.

So I have a content.txt and a header.txt.

**/C copy /B \filepath\header.txt + \filepath\content.txt \filepath\result.txt**

What I want to do at this stage it append the data to the result.txt so it becomes result_09102019.txt.

How do I achieve that within the snippet of code I have above?

Comment: suggestion - explore the use of variables https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22526405/store-filename-in-variable-and-create-tables-with-the-filename-in-ssis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not using an Execute Process Task now in order to achieve the filename.

Instead using an Execute SQL Task to simply write the result set to a variable - which I then point at me Flat File Connection.

**select 'filename_' + format(getdate(), 'yyyyMMddHHmm') + '.csv'**

The single row result set gets written to a variable called OutputFileName.

I then have an OutputFolder variable and then combine the OutputFolder and OutputFileName to another variable called OutputPath.

Output path is then added via an Expression to the file connection.

Answer (score 0):

suggestion - explore the use of variables in building up file names.

[Store filename in variable and create tables with the filename in SSIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22526405/store-filename-in-variable-and-create-tables-with-the-filename-in-ssis)